# The 'InnerHandler' property must be null. 'DelegatingHandler' instances provided to 'HttpMessageHandlerBuilder' must not be reused or cached

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a custome message handler in a MAUI Blazor App for handling API request handling like Loading spinner, defining request header,and checking api exception

```
public class CustomHttpRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

}
```

and there is another httpclientHandler for handling SSL pinning

```
public class HttpsValidation : HttpClientHandler
{
public HttpsValidation()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.Brotli;
    UseProxy = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
   
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = OnValidateCertificate;
}
}
```

assigning the two handler in DI as follow

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<HttpClient>(
    "MyhttpClient",
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl)
    ).ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder => builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    }
    ).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpsValidation())
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomHttpRequestHandler>();
```

defining the http client in RestService as follow

`_httpClient = _thttpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyhttpClient");`

Really the app is working fine but sometimes this issue appears suddenly even sometimes when the app is idle for a while I get this error as follow

*blazor.webview.js:1 The 'InnerHandler' property must be null. 'DelegatingHandler' instances provided to 'HttpMessageHandlerBuilder' must not be reused or cached.
Handler: 'CustomHttpRequestHandler '*

Expected the app to run fine without any issues

Comment: It is recommended to enable more verbose logging for the CustomHttpRequestHandler in order to track the creation of the CustomHttpRequestHandler instance, especially if this exception occurs after working for a period of time.

Answer (score 3):

According to the error. You are re-using the `CustomHttpRequestHandler` class which is inherited from `DelegatingHandler`.

You must not reuse the instance that was used once. You need to recreate the instance for every request you make.

there are two options to manage it.

something like below might help you out :

```
public class CustomHttpRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CustomHttpRequestHandler()
    {
        InnerHandler = null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

or you need to find the way to add `CustomHttpRequestHandler`  as `Transient` in your application configuration.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion to set InnerHandler to null but didn't work,and by the way any Httphandler is injected as Transient

Comment: Thanks a lot for making handler a transient dependency tip! You saved my day.

Comment: I believe making it transient is overkill.  Making it scoped is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by DI as Transient as follow

```
services.AddTransient<CustomHttpRequestHandler>();
```

and it's working fine now

Comment: lol, this was my 2nd option in the answer right beneath the sample code.